# Will someone stop the multiple editing of the "chemical lobotomy" question?

Tags: discussion

[Deliberate destruction of a person with drugs. A synonym to chemical lobotomy?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/96529/deliberate-destruction-of-a-person-with-drugs-a-synonym-to-chemical-lobotomy)

This question has undergone continual  editing since being posted yesterday.

The asker keeps reverting it to versions that contain, literally,  paragraphs of unnecessary text. My edit (version **20**), removed three long paragraphs of irrelevant material that preceeded the actual question.

I don't see how including paragraphs of material is necessary to preceed the basic question, which I have pared to this:

> I heard the term "chemical lobotomizing" in a YouTube video. It is in the context of destroying people's brains by injecting the people with certain drugs. I wonder what other verbal phrases could be used here? In some languages "reducing a person to a vegetable" could be used ... but would "reducing a person to a vegetable" sound good in the English? And what other phrases could be used here instead?

Comment: I have flagged it for moderator attention and at this point I'm just going to ignore it until a moderator gets a chance to look it over. Why are you making a new edit though? Just revert to revision 8.

Comment: I flagged it last night, and hopefully a lock will soon put it out of its misery.

Comment: Since this has been addressed, do we still need this discussion around?

Comment: @ColleenV - Because the answer given by TIPS is a good one, I'm inclined to let it stay. That said, if you'd like to edit this question so that it applies to the generic case and doesn't point directly to a specific question, have at it. Just don't start any edit wars ;-)

Comment: @J.R. Thanks. I have "feelings" about the example  question, so I'm limiting myself to just asking what other folks think instead of editing or close voting. I should have limited myself to rolling back that edit just once, and to top it off I picked the wrong revision (I meant to pick 9) so I'm mildly embarrassed that I let a post irritate me that much. We all have our buttons I guess.

Answer (score 7):

Edit wars! One of the oldest traditions of online wikis. Fun, but not for the people involved.

You can "flag for moderator attention" next time this happens, provide enough explanation and disengage, which is the way to go when the OP is not cooperating. All necessary actions will be taken by mods. In this case, though, this meta post will bring enough attention to the post.

Comment: I was actually afraid the meta post would bring attention to it, which is why I flagged it and ignored it. The post is click-bait and the more attention it gets, the more likely it is that people will up-vote the damn thing, and the harder it will be to make the poster understand why it's unsuitable in it's current form.